# How to start timer in Visual Studio 2010 Form Application

Tags: c#, timer

this is my first time posting, but I was wondering how i can get a timer to increment once i start my program. I have the timer and the stop button, and i can get it to start if i have a start button to press, but i want it to start once the application is opened as there are multiple timers one after another in the game i'm making. thanks everyone. i tried searching this, but couldn't find anything. I'm still pretty new to app programming so it's not something i have done before and don't even know what to try for it.

Comment: Share some of your code (even if it's broken) and we'll be able to better assist you.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome,

I would suggest to locate the FormLoad eventhandler (either by double clicking the form or by looking in the properties window (look for the lightening icon) and search for the Load eventhandler.

Or you could try to use the FormShown eventhandler, which will be triggered when the form is actually shown instead of loaded. Depending on what you are trying to achieve, this might be a better option.

Either way, you will need to put

```
Timer.Start()
```

inside such an event handler.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In Form's Load event (doubleclick on form) you can use

```
timer1.Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start a timer by simply calling [Timer.Start()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.start%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

When to call this depends on the trigger. Typically you write this in an event handler, of the "button click event" like you mention, or the app's "app start event" such as the Main method, but this depends on what kind of app (WinForms?) you are writing.

Answer (score 0):

You can start timer on starting the program either by starting the timer in the following way:

```
    public Form1()
       {
        InitializeComponent();
        time.Start();
        time.Tick += time_Tick;
        }
```

or by initiating the timer in Form Load Event Handler

Comment: This is not good idea. Constructor construct object. It never should start any task.

Comment: I didn't say it doesn't work. But starting some tasks in constructor is really bad practice. Constructor should only receive data for creating the object. Start any tasks should be done with functions or events. In more complex application starting something in contructor could cause problems.

Comment: yes, I understand your concern, but for the sake of being minimalistic I posted this code